# Probability of more than 5 responses surveying two locations with different response rates

Tags: probability, self-study

> You are looking for people between 16 to 23 years to answer a survey.
>   Assume houses on First Street, based on copious amounts of empty
>   beer bottles in front yards and your past experience, has a chance of
>   yielding 16 to 23 year olds to answer your survey of 20% per house.
>   Houses on Second Street, based upon baby strollers parked all over
>   the place, has a chance of yielding 16 to 23 year olds to answer your
>   survey of 10% per house. It takes 6 minutes to come over to a home,
>   ring a bell, ask if there are any 16 to 23 year olds, and ask the survey
>   question; for simplicity, assume it’s the same amount of time if
>   no one answered the door, or if there are no 16 to 23 year olds.
>   In one
>   hour, you can survey ten houses. You have an equally efficient partner.
>   You can split up, and survey 10 houses on First Street and 10
>   houses on Second Street. What is the probability that you get more than 5
>   survey replies from 16 to 23 year olds in one hour?

How do I go about answering this?

This is not a homework question, it is merely to enhance my understanding of the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to find the probability of 0, 1, ..., 4 or 5 and then subtract this from 1 (there are lots more ways to get 6 to 20).

$$P(0:5)=\sum_{m=0}^5{\sum_{n=0}^{5-m}{P_1(m)\cdot P_2(n)}}$$

$$P_1(m)=0.2^m \cdot 0.8^{10-m} \cdot {10\choose{m}}$$
$$P_2(m)=0.1^n \cdot 0.9^{10-n} \cdot {10\choose{n}}$$

Doing the arithmatic, I get $1-P(0:5)$ to be about 6.53%